Amazon Interactive Video Service (IVS) StageClientError, Code 1403
Using IVS web sdk v 1.10.0, I get the Stage client error with code 1403 error when trying to connect to stage and subscribe to clients in the stage.
This issue is only present in chromium based browser in linux. Chrome browsers like brave, google chrome and Chromium gets this error. Works in Firefox browser.
Versions:
Google Chrome 124.0.6367.60
Mozilla Firefox 124.0.2
Error message in console below
{
    "err": {
        "name": "StageClientError",
        "code": 1403,
        "token": {
            "analyticsTracker": {
                "sharedProperties": {
                    "browser": "5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
                    "browser_family": "chrome",
                    "browser_version": "123.0",
                    "customer_id": "ivs",
                    "host": "localhost",
                    "os_name": "Linux",
                    "os_version": "undefined",
                    "platform": "web",
                    "global_session_id": "UUID",
                    "session_id": "UUID",
                    "sdk_version": "1.10.0",
                    "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
                },
                "spadeClient": {
                    "spadeUrl": "https://broadcast.stats.live-video.net/"
                },
                "queuedEvents": [],
                "sessionId": "UUID",
                "flushInterval": 23
            },
......
        "tag": "webrtc_source:tag",
        "location": "StagePeerClient.start",
        "remoteParticipantId": "id",
        "fatal": false,
        "nominal": true
    },
    "log": "Subscribe attempt failed",
    "scope": "StageSubscription"

}



How do I fix this? This Issue only comes for chrome based browsers.
No issue in Firefox.
Need solutions to connect to stage for chrome browsers.
